# Word 2019 Mac: I don't have all bullet points in my word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-powerpoint

I don't have all the symbols for bullet points in word whereas I have them in powerpoint, Can anyone tell how to bring them

See this Word screenshot, I don't have all bullets.

[image: Word screenshot]

This is powerpoint screenshot, where I have all bullets I want.

[image: Powerpoint screenshot]

Comment: If you add a bullet to your document (using any bullet style you do have), and then in the document, does the context menu show the same set? I'm wondering if they are really missing or whether the space devoted to displaying them in the ribbon (which is what I assume your screenshot is) just isn't big enough to display them all.

Comment: I followed what you said but there is no context menu, I guess bullets are missing in my word, Is there any way to bring them back??

Comment: There should be a context menu - read this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_mac-mso_mac2011/wheres-the-right-click-menu-in-microsoft-word-for/e8a7db0d-f3bb-439a-9b26-7fbe1146683e

Comment: What is mouse pad in this website : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_mac-mso_mac2011/wheres-the-right-click-menu-in-microsoft-word-for/e8a7db0d-f3bb-439a-9b26-7fbe1146683e

Comment: a better word for it would be "track pad"

Comment: You may click "Define New Bulletpoint" > Bullet, choose the symbols you need. "[Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLLTt.png)". [Used symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6MD7.png) will be listed.